# Is a line to ground fault always 3 times the zero sequence current?

Tags: power

I'm a little confused, I was provided the 3IO current and I was under the impression that is the bolted 3 phase current but now I am suspecting that it is 3 times Io which is the zero sequence current. My question here is, can I always assume that the single line to ground fault current 3 times the zero sequence current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a symmetrical system we know that we can find the zero, forward, and negative sequence currents as follows [1, 2, 3]:

$$  \begin{bmatrix} I^0_a \\ I^1_a \\ I^2_a \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & a^2 & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I_a \\ I_b \\ I_c \end{bmatrix}$$

However, for a single line-to-ground fault we are assuming that all current flows through the faulted line which means our other two line currents are zero, therefore:

$$ I_b = I_c = 0 $$

Substituting the above into our matrix we can find that:

$$  \begin{bmatrix} I^0_a \\ I^1_a \\ I^2_a \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & a^2 & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I_a \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ I^0_a = I^1_a = I^2_a = \frac{1}{3}I_a$$

$$ \therefore I_a = 3I^0_a$$

---

**Reference:**

[1]  H. Saadat, *"Power System Analysis"*, 3rd ed., 2010, p. 460

[2]  A. Amberg, and A. Rangel, *"Tutorial on Symmetrical Components Part 1: Examples"*, 2013 [Online]. Available: https://selinc.com/api/download/100686/ [Accessed Oct. 2, 2019].

[3]  A. Amberg, and A. Rangel, *"Tutorial on Symmetrical Components Part 2: Answer Key"*, 2013 [Online]. Available: https://selinc.com/api/download/100688/ [Accessed Oct. 2, 2019].

Comment: Can I get a source for this? Thanks in advanced for your help!

Comment: @stan_tj see the edited information. I personally reference the textbooks at my desk (first reference) but the information is widely available online (second reference) and in many other textbooks. If you're looking for further readings your keyword is `symmetrical components`.